# Trouble with Value in recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, singly-linked-list

I was trying out a leetcode question the Add Two Numbers one. Where you add element from 2 linked lists. with one example being Input: l1 = [2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4] Output: [7,0,8]. I have come up with a solution but when testing on case l1 = [0], l2 = [1]; my program returns [2]. Because my carry variable is set to true, but I can't figure out why. I am unsure if I did some odd cody thing or if it something in the recursion. Been looking at it for a while and I just can't figure out why.

My code:

```
let carry = false;
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
    if(l1===null && l2===null){
        return carry? new ListNode(1,undefined):null;
    }
    else if(l1===null){
        let number = carry?  l2.val + 1:l2.val;
        carry = number >= 10;
        number = carry? number-10:number;
        return  new ListNode(number, addTwoNumbers(l1,l2.next));
    }
    else if(l2===null){
        let number = carry?   l1.val + 1:l1.val;
        carry = number >= 10;
        number = carry? number-10:number;
        return  new ListNode(number, addTwoNumbers(l1.next,l2));
    }
    else{
        let number = carry? l1.val + l2.val + 1:l1.val + l2.val;
        carry = number >= 10;
        number = carry? number-10:number;
        return new ListNode(number, addTwoNumbers(l1.next,l2.next));
    }
};
```

I expected it to output correctly like the other tests. The correct output for l1=[0]and l2=[1] being [1].

Comment: I'm not sure how leetcode testing works, but if they run the tests back to back against your code, is it possible that the previous test case ended with carry being equal to `true`? I'd recommend setting carry to false in your first if statement `if(l1===null && l2===null)` and see if that helps

Comment: I can't run this code, but carry since each subsequent calculation uses the possible carry of the previous one, you should pass it as a third parameter:
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2, lastcarry) {
  ....
}
so the first call is: addTwoNumbers(a, b, 0)

Comment: Yes leetcode was ending in a test case where carry = true which was carrying over. So it was fix by implementing @Portal 's suggestion thanks.